# How can I perform a calculation in mysql with result variables, did try sum () but does not work here

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out how to do the calculation, i know how to calculate it on the result in php. but i am sure there must be a way to do it in the query.

i need the projectTotal and the opdrachtTotal in the result

```
SELECT
TABLE_PROJECTEN.id,
TABLE_PROJECTEN.code as pCode,
TABLE_OPDRACHTEN.code as oCode,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t_kosten.aantal * t_kosten.bedrag),0) FROM `t_kosten` WHERE t_kosten.id_ref_project = TABLE_PROJECTEN.id) AS projectKosten,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t_opbrengsten.aantal * t_opbrengsten.bedrag),0) FROM `t_opbrengsten` WHERE t_opbrengsten.id_ref_project = TABLE_PROJECTEN.id) AS projectOpbrengsten,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t_kosten.aantal * t_kosten.bedrag),0)  FROM `t_kosten` WHERE t_kosten.id_ref_opdracht =TABLE_OPDRACHTEN.id) AS opdrachtKosten
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t_opbrengsten.aantal * t_opbrengsten.bedrag),0)  FROM `t_opbrengsten` WHERE t_opbrengsten.id_ref_opdracht =TABLE_OPDRACHTEN.id) AS opdrachtOpbrengsten,
(CALCULATE HERE: projectOpbrengsten-projectKosten) as projectTotal,
(CALCULATE HERE: opdrachtOpbrengsten-opdrachtKosten) as opdrachtTotal
FROM
t_project TABLE_PROJECTEN
LEFT JOIN t_opdracht TABLE_OPDRACHTEN on TABLE_OPDRACHTEN.id_ref_project =  TABLE_PROJECTEN.id
GROUP BY TABLE_OPDRACHTEN.code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform your calculations in individual sub clauses and join with your main query instead of dependent sub queries. Doing this way you can reuse the results of sub clauses tog get your totals.

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.code AS pCode,
    o.code AS oCode,
    COALESCE(tk1.projectKosten,0) AS projectKosten,
    COALESCE(to1.projectOpbrengsten,0) AS projectOpbrengsten,
    COALESCE(tk2.opdrachtKosten,0) AS opdrachtKosten
    COALESCE(to2.opdrachtOpbrengsten,0) AS opdrachtOpbrengsten,
    (COALESCE(to1.projectOpbrengsten,0) - COALESCE(tk1.projectKosten,0)) AS projectTotal,
    (COALESCE(to2.opdrachtOpbrengsten,0) - COALESCE(tk2.opdrachtKosten,0) ) AS opdrachtTotal
FROM t_project p
LEFT JOIN t_opdracht o ON o.id_ref_project =  p.id projectKosten
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_ref_project COALESCE(SUM(aantal * bedrag),0) 
    FROM `t_kosten` 
    GROUP id_ref_project
) tk1 ON  tk1.id_ref_project = p.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_ref_project, SUM(aantal * bedrag) projectOpbrengsten 
    FROM `t_opbrengsten` 
    GROUP BY id_ref_project
) to1 ON to1.id_ref_project = p.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_ref_opdracht ,SUM(t_kosten.aantal * t_kosten.bedrag) opdrachtKosten  
    FROM `t_kosten` 
    GROUP BY id_ref_opdracht
) tk2 ON tk2.id_ref_opdracht =o.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id_ref_opdracht,SUM(aantal * bedrag) AS opdrachtOpbrengsten
    FROM `t_opbrengsten` 
    GROUP BY id_ref_opdracht
) to2 ON to2.id_ref_opdracht =o.id
```

Also i don't see the purpose of doing group by on `TABLE_OPDRACHTEN.code`